# What is the difference between فعل and عمل?

Tags: tafseer, arabic

Allah (SWT) in some places in the Quran uses فعل and in other places uses عمل.

- 2:68

  - فافعلوا ما تومرون
- 41:40

  - اعملوا ما شئتم

Is there a difference between them linguistically or semantically that can give us more insight into the commands of Allah?

I once read somewhere in a tafseer, that فعل is like hearing and seeing (passive), عمل is like listening and watching (active). I can't find it though.

Comment: A simplified difference is that فعل is the most general verb expressing an action therefore we also call verbs in Arabic grammar فعل (as they express an action in the most general of its meaning). A bit more specific action is expressed by the verb عمل, while the most specific action is expressed by the verb صنع (see for example [11:16](https://legacy.quran.com/11/16).